# How to set default startup disk from Mac Startup Manager?

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot, boot-partition

When starting a Mac computer, the <kbd>option</kbd> key can be held down to invoke the Startup Manager. From here, choices are given for possible boot volumes. Is there a way to make the selected volume the new default boot volume?

I wish to boot volumes other than just Windows and OS X. This was possible from OS X System Preferences before El Capitan (OS X 10.11). System Integrity Protection (SIP) now prevents this. Since the Startup Manager ignores SIP and also detects more boot volumes than System Preferences, I now desire to use the Startup Manager to set the default startup volume.

Comment: I'm confused. If you don't want a System Preferences solution, why have you accepted [pun's answer](http://superuser.com/q/1090885/150988#1090886)?

Comment: Am I still confused? More than ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → Startup Disk → Choose the disk and restart

[image]

The next time you start up or restart your computer, your Mac starts up using the operating system on the selected volume.

*Another trick which I cannot verify is to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then Click on the disk after invoking startup manager at boot time.
If the trick works, ↑ upwards pointing arrow should turn into a circle.*

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can you not verify holding down the control key after invoking the Start Up manager?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I haven't tried that method ever and can't try it now as I am using Ubuntu. Read about it at some reliable sources so posted it with a disclaimer.

Comment: I verified the method works on a 2007 iMac and a 2011 iMac. The method did not work on a 2006 iMac. My guess would be that it works on most, if not all, newer Mac models.

Comment: Well the ctrl-key and mouse selection worked (in my Mac Mini 2012 with Catalina (max Apple upgrade) and I have two HD (now using it as an excellent home (max 1440p TV) Win10-computer). Boots steady on the Win10 disk after the selection with ctrl-key.